# Drive.Revisions.list has permission error on Team Drive when it should not

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

In Google Apps Script I am trying to get the revisions of a file.  The code is:

```
    var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(file.getId());
```

When running this on a file on Team Drive I sometimes get the "user does not have the required access" error.  However, when I go to that same file manually I can click on the Activity tab and see the revisions fine.

The script is running as the user, so should have the same permissions.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you the user when errors occur? Perhaps those users do not have permission to view changes to that file. I suggest using a try catch block and logging (to Stackdriver) the user's permissions for the file upon failed access.

Comment: Yes, the script runs as me, and the message in the catch block is my email address.